# Android: MediaPlayer AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS & setOnErrorListener() issue

Tags: java, android, android-audiomanager

I'm creating a music player app.

In that I am checking if my application loses AudioFocus then the playback will stop.
But this is raising one issue that when I play a track - then stop it and - then play a track again, `switch case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS`  is getting called in which I've stopped the player as it is losing focus.

So my own app is losing focus to itself.
Obviously, these were not my intentions.
I wanted it to get called when some other music player requested focus.

```
private OnAudioFocusChangeListener focusChangeListener = new OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
        switch (focusChange) {
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:

            if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                stopPlayback();
            }
            break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
            if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mPlayer.pause();
            }
            break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
            if (!mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                initiatePlayback();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

**There is one more problem**, Exception that I was getting is `IllegalStateException`.

This means when the code reaches inside `case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS`, my musicplayer is in some erroneous state.
So to check that, I registered an `OnErrorListener` using:

```
//Inside Service - onCreate() Method
mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(mErrorListener);
```

But this listener is never gets called. 
I'll appreteate any help.

Answer (score 7):

I had similar issue, I strongly suspect that your `focusChangeListener` is recreated somewhere in your program so you request focus on different instance of `focusChangeListener`. Are you defining it from a service or activity?

The idea is to maintain **a single copy** of your `focusChangeListener` that you pass to `requestAudioFocus()` and `abandonAudioFocus()`; otherwise the AudioManager will consider the request from different source, which can cause the app can lose focus to itself.

You should know that calling `requestAudioFocus()` **on the same listener object** many times does register it *only once* and calling `abandonAudioFocus()` one time is sufficient to release the audio focus.

Few suggestions that can solve your problem:

- Try to define `focusChangeListener` as static object and see if help.
- If your listener is registered in Activity, consider to move to a service so the listener can 
  survive longer.
- To debug this issue, it is very helpful to log the following ** whenever ** you request or abandon focus to ensure that you have, to ensure that you are dealing with the same instance:

  - Your focusChangeListener e.g. `focusChangeListener.hashCode()`
  - Current context object e.g. `context.hashCode()`
  - Current thread id e.g. `Thread.currentThread().getId()`

For example:

```
  Log.d(TAG, String.format("Request audio focus: thread id = %s, context = %s, listener = %s",Thread.currentThread().getId(),context.hashCode(),focusChangeListener hashCode())
```

**Edit:**

Using application context i.e. `getApplicationContext()` can solve the issue as well.

Comment: how to maintain the single copy of focusChangeListener ?? I have   makes use of singleton but there are activity switching player get stop that focus loss ... can you help me ...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately IllegalStateExceptions don't trigger the OnErrorListener call. You will have to try/catch around portions of your code for IllegalStateExceptions where they may be triggered.