# Yet one more mediaPlayer IllegalStateException: screen timeout

Tags: java, android, media-player, illegalstateexception

I have made/downloaded a Java mediaplayer class for Android that is working well, except that at screen timeout or when turning it off by hand, when resuming, I get an IllegalStateException when trying a `mediaPlayer.isPlaying()`.

Googling I found that this is probably the mediaplayer being in error state. I then tried `try {...} catch(IllegalStateException...` thing, but I am adding too many, and the thing is being a big mess out of control (and without success).

Then I tried something like:

```
mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                mp.release();
                return false;
            }
```

but it is not working, still getting the IllegalStateException error. 
(EDIT: BTW, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860046/android-mediaplayer-audiofocus-loss-setonerrorlistener-issue) it says that " IllegalStateExceptions don't trigger the OnErrorListener call". Is this correct??)

So, my question(s):

1) What is happening at screen timeout that puts mediaplayer into error state?
2) How can I prevent this from happening?
3) What do I need to put inside the mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener?
4) Did I miss something for the error listener, need to handle it somehow?

Sorry... newbie here.

EDIT: I was required to add the call, so here is the whole class:

```
package com.floritfoto.apps.ave;

import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener;

public class Music implements OnCompletionListener{
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    boolean isPrepared = false;

    public Music(FileDescriptor fileDescriptor){
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try{
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fileDescriptor);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            isPrepared = true;
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
                public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                    mp.release();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        } catch(Exception ex){
            throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't load music, uh oh!");
        }
    }

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        synchronized(this){
            isPrepared = false;
        }       
    }               

    public void play() {
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            return;
        }   
        try{
            synchronized(this){
                if(!isPrepared){
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                }
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        } catch(IllegalStateException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }   

    public void stop() {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        synchronized(this){
            isPrepared = false;
        }       
    }       

    public void switchTracks(){
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }   

    public void pause() {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }

    public boolean isPlaying() {
        return mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
    }

    public boolean isLooping() {
        return mediaPlayer.isLooping();
    }

    public void setLooping(boolean isLooping) {
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(isLooping);
    }

    public void setVolume(float volumeLeft, float volumeRight) {
        mediaPlayer.setVolume(volumeLeft, volumeRight);
    }

    public String getDuration() {
        return String.valueOf((int)(mediaPlayer.getDuration()/1000));
    }
    public void dispose() {
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            stop();
        }
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
}
```

And this is the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(21110): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(21110): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.floritfoto.apps.ave/com.floritfoto.apps.ave.OpenBird}: java.lang.IllegalStateException
E/AndroidRuntime(21110):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2718)
E/AndroidRuntime(21110):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2674)
E/AndroidRuntime(21110):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2652)
E/AndroidRuntime(21110):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:127)
E/AndroidRuntime(21110):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1170)
E/AndroidRuntime(21110):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(21110):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(21110):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
E/AndroidRuntime(21110):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(21110):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(21110):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
E/AndroidRuntime(21110):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
E/AndroidRuntime(21110):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(21110): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
E/AndroidRuntime(21110):        at android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(21110):        at com.floritfoto.apps.ave.Music.dispose(Music.java:101)
E/AndroidRuntime(21110):        at com.floritfoto.apps.ave.OpenBird.onPause(OpenBird.java:211)
E/AndroidRuntime(21110):        at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:4563)
E/AndroidRuntime(21110):        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1198)
E/AndroidRuntime(21110):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2705)
E/AndroidRuntime(21110):        ... 12 more
W/ActivityManager( 1864):   Force finishing activity r.intent.getComponent().flattenToShortString()
```

Comment: You should post the whole call stack

Answer (score 0):

Try to check mediaPlayer against null before you call isPlaying() Replace your isPlaying() method with this:

```
@Override
public boolean isPlaying()
{
    super.isPlaying();
if ( mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying() )
    return true;
else
    return false;   
}
```

Comment: Actually, I get exactly the same error at the same line, so mediaPlayer does not seem to be null. Well, I need to remove the `@Override` and `super.isPlaying();` you suggested because I get "method must override superclass method".

Comment: I just checked, and if I turn off the screen while playing, the music stops immediately. Maybe this info helps?

Comment: Does it still crash with the exception or just stop plays without any errors?

Comment: Same exception at isPlaying(). So my only question is very simple: Why does music stops when screen is off? Obviously I don't want this behavior. Maybe I should start a service??