# Is there a way to get the app that is playing audio?

Tags: android

From what I have observed in my android phone - Only one app is able to play audio at a time.

I am looking into creating an android service which plays the next song when volume up button is long pressed. Similar behaviour for the case when the volume down button is long pressed.

So I need to find the app which is currently playing audio.

Is this possible? If yes, would appreciate pointers on how I can do this.

Comment: Related: [Retrieving the application name that has audio focus change](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31616084/295004) and [Android - is it possible to find out which app has audiofocus?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13273711/295004)

Comment: @MorrisonChang - Read these. Seems like there is no standard way to do this.